# EE5: Saving long entries in Control Panel doesn't save and shows website homepage

Tags: channel-entries, saving

My client reported that when trying to create a new entry via the Control Panel, she had to add 1 paragraph at a time and keep resaving the entry. At a certain point, she couldn't add any more content to it, it would process the form, but the added content wasn't saved, and the system would show the homepage of the site (with the URL for the edit entry page).

The site is otherwise working fine. I thought it may be htaccess so I messed with a few things there, no change (and it doesn't make sense that this would be the problem in hindsight). I disabled all extensions via config override, that didn't change anything either. Checked the PHP and apache error logs, nothing there. Repaired and optimized db tables. Nothing.

Any ideas?

EE 5.2.3
PHP 7.1.32

Comment: Try increasing `max_input_vars` and `post_max_size` variables in php.ini

Comment: max_input_vars were at 10,000 and post_max_size at 64M. I upped some other values as well. This allowed me to save the content, but still showed the homepage once the save was complete.

Comment: It sounds like mod_rewrite may be tripping things up. Check your server to see if any rules are being triggered on save.